# lineheight in themepunch library does not work

Tags: html, jquery, slider, jquery-ui-slider

There seems to be a bug in my web application, which is that the line height is not working **using** the theme punch library. The theme punch library encodes inline styles onto an element, so even if I wrote down

```html
<h1 style="line-height: 15px !important;">Hello</h1>
```

it still would not work. Keep in mind themepunch uses jquery and a bit of HTML. I'll display my user perspective problem and the developer's problem.

**User's Perspective**:

[image]

Do you see how ugly the line height is? and also I would like to shift the "Learn More" to the left a bit.

**Developer's Perspective**

Consider the following code:

Slider.html

```html
 <!-- Slider Area Start Here-->
 <div class="slider-area1">
    <div id="rev_slider_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container" data-alias="photography1" style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;">
        <div id="rev_slider_1" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" data-version="5.0.7" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <!-- SLIDE  -->
                <li data-index="rs-1" data-transition="slideoververtical">
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="../assets/assets/images/bg/bg-1.jpeg" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                    <!-- All these attributes are themepunch library attrs, but a lot of them are not working. I am not sure if it's because I didn't initalize something or not,
            but I'll show the Jquery initalization. In case I am missing something, please let me know. Keep in mind, I am only interested in data-lineheight ... -->
                    <div class="tp-caption slide-text-one tp-resizeme" id="slide-1-layer-1"  data-frames='[{

                      "delay": 500,
                      "speed": 300,
                      "from": "opacity: 0",
                      "to": "opacity: 1"
               
                  }, {
               
                      "delay": "wait",
                      "speed": 300,
                      "to": "opacity: 0"
               
                  }]'  data-x="center" data-hoffset="['10','30','','0']" data-lineheight="['32', '32', '32', '24']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-100','-100','-30','-100']" data-fontsize="['inherit','20','20','17']"  data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:right;y:0;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 5; white-space: nowrap; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; line-height: 30px;">
                        <h1 appResponsiveDirective id="lineHeight">muscle <span>power</span></h1>
                    </div>

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption slide-text-two tp-resizeme"  data-frames='[{

                      "delay": 500,
                      "speed": 300,
                      "from": "opacity: 0",
                      "to": "opacity: 1"
               
                  }, {
               
                      "delay": "wait",
                      "speed": 300,
                      "to": "opacity: 0"
               
                  }]' id="slide-1-layer-2"  
                  data-lineheight="['256', '256', '256', '256']" data-x="center" data-y="['center','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-0','-0','70','0']" data-fontsize="['60','60','60','30']"  data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; line-height: 30px;">
                        <h1 appResponsiveDirective class="text-center" id="lineHeight" style="line-height: 15px !important;" >fitness is not a destination<br> it is a way of life</h1>
                    </div>

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
                    <div appResponsiveDirective id="lineHeight" class="tp-caption rev-btn white-btn" id="slide-1-layer-4"  data-frames='[{

                      "delay": 500,
                      "speed": 300,
                      "from": "opacity: 0",
                      "to": "opacity: 1"
               
                  }, {
               
                      "delay": "wait",
                      "speed": 300,
                      "to": "opacity: 0"
               
                  }]' data-x="center" data-lineheight="['32', '32', '32', '24']" data-hoffset="['65','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','bottom','bottom']" data-voffset="['100','130','200','200']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power3.easeOut;" data-style_hover="c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bc:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);" data-transform_in="y:bottom;s:1200;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[175%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" 
data-start="1250" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"rs-164","delay":""}]' data-responsive_offset="on" 
data-responsive="off" style="z-index: 8; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 18px; line-height: 15px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 30px;">learn more
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- Slide 2, 3, .. -->
</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--#rev_slider_1_wrapper-->
</div>
<!-- Slider Area End Here-->
```

Jquery initalization:

```
/*
            Keep in mind, this is not really my code so I don't know what most of these properties do
        */
        $("#rev_slider_1").show().revolution({
            sliderType: "standard",
            sliderLayout: "fullscreen",
            dottedOverlay: "none",
            autoPlay: false,
            spinner: "spinner4",
            navigation: {
                keyboardNavigation: "off",
                keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                mouseScrollNavigation: "off",
                onHoverStop: "on",
                touch: {
                    touchenabled: "on",
                    swipe_threshold: 75,
                    swipe_min_touches: 1,
                    swipe_direction: "horizontal",
                    drag_block_vertical: false
                },
                arrows: {
                    enable: true,
                    style: 'metis',
                    tmp: '',
                    rtl: false,
                    hide_onleave: true,
                    hide_onmobile: true,
                    hide_under: 0,
                    hide_over: 9999,
                    hide_delay: 200,
                    hide_delay_mobile: 1200,
                    left: {
                        container: 'slider',
                        h_align: 'left',
                        v_align: 'center',
                        h_offset: 20,
                        v_offset: 0
                    },
                    right: {
                        container: 'slider',
                        h_align: 'right',
                        v_align: 'center',
                        h_offset: 20,
                        v_offset: 0
                    }
                },
            },
            responsiveLevels: [1240, 1024, 778, 480],
            gridwidth: [1240, 1024, 778, 480],
            gridheight: [868, 768, 960, 720],
            lazyType: "none",
            shadow: 0,
            shuffle: "off",
            autoHeight: "off",
        });
        // revolution slider end
```